# Is it ok to render a React element multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a functional component rendering 5 icons.

This can be done like this:

```
export default const Icons = () =>
    <div>
        <Icon/>
        <Icon/>
        <Icon/>
        <Icon/>
        <Icon/>
    </div>;
```

But it can also be done like this:

```
const icon = <Icon/>;

export default const Icons = () =>
    <div>
        {icon}
        {icon}
        {icon}
        {icon}
        {icon}
    <div/>;
```

The difference is that in the second case, only one React element is created using `React.createElement`.

---

**Is it discouraged to render a React element multiple times?**

If so, why is that? If not, are there any performance or size benefits to be had by rendering a React element multiple times?

Comment: The first, or the second it's ok, you can re-use a component into the same component couple time. 

I would say, it's always use in professionnal apps, it's call component logic

Answer (score 1):

It is ok. You can also map over some array of data that you can use to pass down to your components as props.

```
const altTags = ['me', 'dog', 'cat'];
const icon = <Icon/>;    
export default const Icons = () =>
        <div>
           {this.altTags.map(tag => <Icon alt={tag} />)}
        </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking it wrongly. Both are the same. There's no difference between them. In the second case, you're just assigning to component `<Icon />` and each time you call `{icon}` will actually call to the component `<Icon />`.

I would rather choose to use first. Because, I don't need to assign unnecessarily which calls to the component.

Here's what will happen when using second case:

1. Look for `{icon}`
2. Look for assigned component `<Icon />`
3. Render `<Icon />` component

Here's what will happen when using first case:

1. Look for `<Icon />`
2. Render `<Icon />` component

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up? This logic seems weird since `<Icon/>` (= `React.createElement(...)`) is only called once.

Comment: It's simple javascript logic. BTW, console is your friend.

Comment: It doesn't seem simple to me, so please elaborate. Also, how does console help me with this issue?

Comment: Do console in the `<Icon />`  component.

Comment: Why? I know the render method runs once for each `icon`, because there are 5 icons in the DOM and the virtual DOM is reflects that. But it should still be the same React element being rendered right, since I only create one React element?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok but is not really efficient from the architectural point of view.If we follow the principles of SOLID development this break a few rules.
From a maintenability and reusability point of view this can be improved.
If you create a property in the component that specify how many icons you want and in the render method you use a loop to iterate and create the icons this code will be much better.